# Chrome incorrectly rendering pixels as fractions

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

Edit: Resolved. Rather than resetting the Zoom to 100%, the "View < Actual Size" resolved the issue.

I've been having an issue with Chrome rendering divs as fractions and not exactly as the specified numbers.

For example:

HTML

```
<div class='tile'>foo</div>
```

CSS

```
.tile {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: outset;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}
```

Rather than being rendered as 2px, the border-width is "1.8181817531585693px" inferred both from the Chrome Developer Tools > Elements > Computed and using the debugger with jQuery .css function.

A few additional things to note is that this only happens when it's loaded on an FTP, not locally. This issue also doesn't occur in either Firefox or Safari. Any ideas or explanation as to what exactly Chrome is doing, or the solution to it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is all of the code you're using in your question?

Comment: I get this exact value when zooming such an element. Are you sure, your zoom is at 100%?

Comment: Does the appearance change depending on whether Chrome is using whole or partial pixels?

Comment: Thanks for the lead Max K. I actually tried resolving the issue before by setting the zoom to 100% and also resetting the zoom. But in looking at the View menu, I decided to select the 'Actual Size' option, which apparently did resolve it. Thanks!

Comment: A question should be edited to be more understandable as a question, not to contain its answer. It is impossible to say what the question really is (e.g. how you inferred that “the border-width is "1.8181817531585693px"”).

Comment: I don't think this should have been put on hold.  Anyone who has actually had his problem I think understands what he is asking.  The browser is not rendering as expected, not exactly.  You might want to read my answer carefully below, because the answer to this problem is not any simple fix, but rather to understand the nature of what is going on so you can work with it.  my 2c.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is they are dealing with real numbers that are binary internally, and things must be done quickly.

So some numerical corners are probably being cut, that are normally not noticeable to the average web page viewer, that is if a page is designed so that it is not noticeable.

Go figure, I know, you would think that browsers would be more accurate, but I have found that even with the most careful and detailed control of my css, there seem to be rounding errors that play havoc with small details when displayed.

First, I would suggest you use **em** rather than **px**.  I know you might have to start over with your css, but I have found it to be more reliable, screen to screen.  Remember modern pages are not based on pixels.  They are dynamic beasts that can be zoomed in and out, and squished narrower and still must output something reasonable.

Also I would suggest rethinking how you are laying out your page so such small details are not an issue.  In carpentry the skilled artisan knows how to hide the rough edges with a molding.

I have a very accurate web page I use to generate to a special printed flyer.  It was a royal pain to force html and css into something they didn't want to do, which was be accurate.

Also I can test my production site on the 5 major browsers, right on top of each other so I can see little differences when I switch between them, from one browser to another.  They are all off just a little from each other in various ways, and really there is no way to make them accurate.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually quite helpful to think about in the long run.