# 1px border-bottom width is .8px when inspected?

Tags: css, width, border

I have a ul which is 200px high and four li inside, each 49px high w/ 1px border-bottom.

when I inspected the li's in Chrome, the (rendered) border bottom is .800000001912px.

I have percentage WIDTHS but not percentage heights. Why are my bottom-borders behaving weirdly?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712013/chrome-incorrectly-rendering-pixels-as-fractions, you are possibly zoomed out? Otherwise that's odd, I can't really imagine what .8 pixel is supposed to look like ;p

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem in js fiddle or js bin or something like that? Are you sure your CSS isn't getting overwritten somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This could only be happening if you have a `margin` or `padding` or `border-top` value on the `<ul>` or `<li>` elements that you are not accounting for in your calculations, because it might be adjusting the border to fit to its container height.

Here is a JS Fiddle tested in chrome that does exactly what you said, but it definitely renders the bottom border at a value of 1px: http://jsfiddle.net/j5am2sqe/

html:

```
<ul class="list">
   <li class="list-item" />
   <li class="list-item" />
   <li class="list-item" />
   <li class="list-item" />
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul {
    height: 200px;
}

li {
    height: 49px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```