# flexbox align-items: center rendering differently on chrome vs firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

While centering a `div` inside another `div` with `flexbox`, I noticed that firefox and chrome are rendering it differently.

In my case, I have 3 divs. Each has a `display:flex` and `justify-content:center` & `align-items:center`.

**On Chrome:** The innermost div seems to be a bit to the `right` instead of exactly at the `center`.

**On Firefox:** The div is correctly rendered at the center of its parent div.

The code for the same can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-pine-q63b5?file=/src/App.js

Firefox version: **69.0 (64 bit)**

Chrome version: **84.0.4147.105 (64 bit)**

MacOS Catalina: **10.15.6**

Answer (score 4):

**FINAL EDIT:** Looks like Chrome fixed this and it's no longer an issue.

This is due to pixel precision. Chrome fails to display correctly with positions with pixel decimals, while Firefox doesn't. As your child element has 7px width and your parent 14px, the side margins of the child are 3.5px, but it rounds up to 4px. If you set your child's width to 6px or 8px, or your parent's to 15px it will get fixed in Chrome.

**EDIT:** It seems in some cases you can force Chrome to calculate decimal pixels by using decimal pixels in the element's width. [There is some rounding up going on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712013/chrome-incorrectly-rendering-pixels-as-fractions) and it seems you need to double-check each case, but apparently percentages and relative units (rem, em, vw, vh) are more reliable. See the examples:

- Yellow fails in Chrome.
- Orange fails in Firefox.
- Teal fails in both.
- White, works precisely?

```css
div {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background: black;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
div:after{
  content: '';
  background: white;
}
div:nth-child(1):after {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
}
div:nth-child(2):after {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: teal;
}
div:nth-child(3):after {
  width: 6.1px;
  height: 6.1px;
  background: orange;
}
div:nth-child(4):after {
  width: 42%;
  height: 42%;
}
div:nth-child(5):after {
  width: 50.6%;
  height: 50.6%;
  background: orange;
}
div:nth-child(6):after {
  width: .43em;
  height: .43em;
  background: orange;
}
div:nth-child(7) {
  width: 12.5px;
  height: 12.5px;
}
div:nth-child(7):after {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: yellow;
}
div:nth-child(8) {
  width: 1.34%;
  height: 12.5px;
}
div:nth-child(8):after {
  width: 5.5px;
  height: 5.5px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div title="pixels if subtraction equals integer works"></div>
<div title="pixels if subtraction equals decimal is bugged"></div>
<div title="if you use decimal pixels in the child bugged in Firefox"></div>
<div title="percentage seems to work"></div>
<div title="decimal percentage might fail in Firefox"></div>
<div title="em also works"></div>
<div title="decimal pixels in the parent is bugged"></div>
<div title="parent's % + child decimal pixels also bugged"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I had noticed that when I reduced the width it was getting aligned. So is there no other way of achieving pixel perfection and alignment without manipulating the dimensions?

Comment: I researched a little deeper, made some tests and edited the answer, hope it helps

Comment: If you are using very small sizes like in the examples I would go with precise rounded pixel numbers, for bigger elements half of a pixel will not be noticed even by Ironman ;)