CSS border size is different in chrome devtools
I set the border size of 2nd div tag as 4px.
But the chrome devtools shows that the border size is 3.333px.
I wanna know why it is different.


https://stackoverflow.com/q/20712013/1427878

might be a bug. what happens when you resize the actual document so that the documents width is greater than it is now?
